# How to use Translation Editor in Java file

Tags: java, android, xml

I need to know, how to translate text when the text is written in java class, normally, I use strings in xml, but how can I use translate when the text is written in java. example in code below.

How to allow to translate the India,Pakistan,Australia and more.. is there any way to write it so that it can be translated?

```
public class ExpandableListDataPump {
public static HashMap<String, List<String>> getData() {
    HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    List<String> cricket = new ArrayList<String>();
    cricket.add("India");
    cricket.add("Pakistan");
    cricket.add("Australia");
    cricket.add("England");
    cricket.add("South Africa");

    List<String> football = new ArrayList<String>();
    football.add("Brazil");
    football.add("Spain");
    football.add("Germany");
    football.add("Netherlands");
    football.add("Italy");

    List<String> basketball = new ArrayList<String>();
    basketball.add("United States");
    basketball.add("Spain");
    basketball.add("Argentina");
    basketball.add("France");
    basketball.add("Russia");

    expandableListDetail.put("CRICKET TEAMS", cricket);
    expandableListDetail.put("FOOTBALL TEAMS", football);
    expandableListDetail.put("BASKETBALL TEAMS", basketball);
    return expandableListDetail;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166781/how-to-settext-of-a-public-string)

But I think you should keep your strings in `string.xml` for Translation and Maintain different `string(ln).xml` according to the required language